# Pass dynamic data to router-link.

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to pass a dynamic path to vue-router but I can't seem to give it the correct syntax. Here is what I'm trying.

```
<li v-on:click="$emit('closeDropdown')"><router-link to="item.route" id="button">{{ item.title }}</router-link></li>
```

Is just wrapping it in quotes not enough because this is what I see when I inspect the elements: `href="#/item.route"` for all items.

#### PARENT COMPONENT

```
<UserDropdownList v-for="item in userDropdownItems" v-bind:item="item"></UserDropdownList>

 data: function () {
  return {
    userDropdownItems: [
      { title: 'Profile', route: "/profile" },
      { title: 'Users', route: "/users" }
    ]
   }
 }
```

How can I access the route property for the `Router-link` to attribute?

Comment: After reading your question again, I believe my second approach is the one you're seeking.

Comment: Yep! adding the `:` before the `to` did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Using Dynamic Route Parameters

If you take a look at the [`vue-router`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) documentation, what you're describing sounds very much like a job for [dynamic route parameters](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html):

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    // dynamic segments start with a colon
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User, name: 'user' }
  ]
});
```

Then, to [generate a link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) via `<router-link>` for said route, you'd do the following:

```
<!-- named route -->
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { id: 123 }}">User</router-link>
```

---

#### Directly using variable with `router-link`

To use variables in a router link, all you have to do is this:

```
<router-link :to="item.route" id="button">{{ item.title }}</router-link>
```

Adding a colon (:) before the `to` attribute tells Vue that you're about to use some javascript in there.

---

#### Using query parameters

Instead of using dynamic route parameters OR js variables, you could use the query option instead:

```
<!-- with query, resulting in `/register?plan=private` -->
<router-link :to="{ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }}">Register</router-link>
```

---

**Hope this helps!** I've attached all the documentation sources where I found this. I highly recommend giving it a solid look through, as it is one of the most well-written documentation sites I've ever come across.